# How to correctly convert unsigned char to CString and once again, reversely convert to the result of CString to unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have problems with Converting unsigned char to CString and reversely, converting the result of converted CString to unsigned char.

first, I try to using CString.append();.

///////////////////////////

```
CString result2;
CString result3;
unsigend char unchar_result[9];
unchar_result = {143, 116, 106, 224, 101, 104, 57, 157};
unchar_result[8] = NULL;

for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
     result2=(char)temp[i];
     result3.append(result2);
}
```

//////////////////////////

as a result, I think result3 was correctly substituted.

if I saw 'unchar_result' by the ASCII code, then unchar_result = "?tj?eh9?" and result3 was "?tj?eh9?" too.

But I want to reversely convert (CString)result3 to unsigned char matrix.

```
unsigned char a;
unsigned char testdecode[8];
for(int i=0; i<8 ; i++){
  a=result3.GetAt(i);
  testdecode[i]=a

}
```

after converting, the result was "?tj?eh9?" but, the value was { 63, 116, 106, 63, 101, 104, 57, 63}... i expect the result was { 143, 116, 106, 224, 101, 104, 57, 157 }.

next, I try again using CStringA.

```
CStringA result6;
result6(unchar_result);
```

and I can see the value through the local variable window of the debug tool. then, result6 was "뢶j?h9앀儆?" moreover int len = result6.GetLength() = 13.

How to correctly convert unsigned char to CString and to do inverse?

Comment: I know that this is not answer for your question, but do you have any particular reason to use CString and char*? If you can use std::string it would be much easier.

Comment: I using 'MFC'. and CString was member variable of Edit Control. so I have to use CString. and Now, I making DES algorithm. So i need unsigned character for to encrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion to CString is pretty easy, just pass the `unsigned char*` to the c'tor. Conversion from `CString` to `unsigned char*` is a little more work, see below.

```
unsigned char orig[] = "hello world";
std::cout << orig << " (unsigned char *)" << std::endl;

// Convert to a CString
CString cstring(orig);
std::cout << cstring << " (CString)" << std::endl;

// Convert to a unsigned char*
const size_t newsize = (cstring.GetLength() + 1);
unsigned char* nstring = new unsigned char[newsize];
strcpy_s((char*)nstring, newsize, cstring);
std::cout << nstring << " (unsigned char*)" << std::endl;
```

Comment: it doesn't compile... strcpy_s((char*)nstring, newsize, cstring) method makes error. It cannot convert 'CString' to 'const char *' i'm so sorry for the truble

Comment: and when i convert to CString unsing CString cstring(orig), it is not correctly work. if unsigned char was over the 127 value(extended ASCII), cstring(orig) was doesn't work... I converted unsigned char temp[9] = { 143, 116, 106, 224, 101, 104, 57, 157, NULL } to CString. Using CString result(temp). but result.GetLenght() = 6...

Comment: Compile error is probably because you have unicode support enabled. I created my project with multi-byte support which compiles and executes just fine. Do you really need to use `unsigned char*` or could you also use a `std::wstring`?

Comment: I don't know about my environment support uni-code. but i think that the computer automatically recognize the character. especially, the character over 127 value was not accepted rightly. and i have to use the value over 127. because i making encryption algorithm. so if I encrypt plain text consist of alphabet, number and some of special letter, (maybe the value of plain text was between around 40 to 122) the result of encryption will be contain value over 127. and I don't know How to deal with the character over the 127 value.

Comment: just to make sure I'm getting you right: you have some edit field in a GUI from which you retrieve the content as `CString`. Then you encrypt with some algorithm and the result of that encryption is an array of `unsigned char`. You then want to display the result of the encryption in the GUI again? This is not possible, because the encryption result will most likely contain non-printable characters. The encryption result is not human readable any more - it's binary.

Comment: Oh my god... I used CString as the parameter. What i mean is that all method had CString parameter. So I will try to gain the CString text from edit field. And after Encryt the text, I will send  the result of encryted text to edit control. And again I will get the text from the edit control(It is Encryted text) and I want to decryt the text... but, as your answer, It can't do that... i'm so sad...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at documentation, you can construct CString from a pointer to char buffer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). [All supported operations for CString class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), you may use GetBuffer, function to get a pointer to internal buffer of the CString, call ReleaseBuffer to take ownership of this buffer.