# UCHAR * to CString conversion and CString to UCHAR * to conversion in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am new to vc++. How to convert `UCHAR *` value to `CString`and CString to UCHAR *

```
CString str;
UCHAR * pBuffer;
......Memmory allocation..
str.format(_T("%d"),pBuffer);
```

But its not working. Second data may be string or int so how to do conversion in proper way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350411/how-to-correctly-convert-unsigned-char-to-cstring-and-once-again-reversely-conv

Comment: In above link answer is accepted. But questioner is not satisfied with answer.

Comment: What EXACTLY does the `UCHAR*` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Second data may be string or int so how to do conversion in proper way.

You have to interpret the `UCHAR*` data as a proper data type when formatting it, eg:

```
// if pBuffer contains 'int' data...
str.format(_T("%d"), *(int*)pBuffer);
```

```
// if pBuffer contains 8bit 'char' data w/ a null terminator...
str.format(_T("%hs"), (char*)pBuffer);

Or:

// if pBuffer contains 8bit 'char' data w/o a null terminator...
str.format(_T("%*hs"), iBufferLen, (char*)pBuffer);
```

And so on...